# Laravel - Password forgotten -> Error DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Argument #1 ($source) must not be empty

Tags: email, laravel-9

I have a problem with **Laravel 9.48**.
When I go to Forgotten Password when logging in and enter my email address.
and then the button "**Send Password Reset Link**" I get the following error message.

**DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Argument #1 ($source) must not be empty**

Can you tell me how I can fix this problem?

[image: Passwort reset]

[image: Error]

Comment: Im really confused, what exactly are you doing? are you generating HTML content? Rather than using Routes + Blade? Is this your own custom authentication system?

Comment: i am unfortunately a laravel beginner. this is the auth system integrated by laravel.

Comment: Well, you for sure made some changes to laravel auth, can you please share what changes you made, specifically if you modified any blades + controllers, the file you are pointing to is a /vendor/ folder which should not be touched.

Comment: The problem I have is that I have not changed this area, so I was wondering why this error suddenly appeared. If I knew which files were doing this password reset, I could overwrite them with a Laravel version that works.

Comment: I have the Problem: Config /mail -> Markdown was activ :(